# How to search not matching pattern in VIM

Tags: regex, string, search, vim

Here is an excerpt of my `.py` file:

```
for i in range(1,nxs-2):
    for j in (1, nts-2):
        dg_cc(dg,sina,cosa,s,r2tanb,omega,L,n,m,xs[i],ts[k],pd)
        dot( dg,F,c1,transa=T )
        dot( c1, dg, ansK1, N, N, alpha=2., beta=1. )
        # linear buckling part
        g = g_cc(m,n,L,xs[i],ts[j],pd)
        Bg = fBg(Bg,cosa,s,L,m,n,xs[i],ts[i],pd)
        dot( g, Bg, ansK1, T, N, alpha=2., beta=1. )
        #
        if pd:
            fdg0(dg0,sina,cosa,s,r2tanb,omega,L,xs[i],ts[j])
            dot( dg0, F, c2, transa=T )
            dot( c2, dg, ansK0, N, N, alpha=2., beta=1. )
for i in (1, nxs-2):
    for j in range(1,nts-2):
        dg_cc(dg,sina,cosa,s,r2tanb,omega,L,n,m,xs[i],ts[n],pd)
        dot( dg,F,c1,transa=T )
        dot( c1, dg, ansK1, N, N, alpha=2., beta=1. )
        # linear buckling part
        g = g_cc(m,n,L,xs[i],ts[j],pd)
        Bg = fBg(Bg,cosa,s,L,m,n,xs[i],ts[j],pd)
        dot( g, Bg, ansK1, T, N, alpha=2., beta=1. )
```

I have to fix all the typos keeping only `ts[j]` and fixing those with `ts[i]` or `ts[n]`, for example.

How do I build my searching pattern in order to get everywhere where `ts[something]` `something NOT equal j`?

Comment: Do you intend to do a search/replace in one action like `:%s` or just build the search pattern and manually fix them?  Also, I don't see any `ts[]` in your code, just `xs[]`.

Comment: just build a search pattern and replace manually, since there are some cases I want to keep, like `ts[0]` (not shown in the example)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

can you try this, see if it works for your requirement?

```
/ts\[[^j]\]
```

Comment: And if the internal variable might be more than a single character, `[^j]+`

Comment: You only need to escape the first square bracket to have the whole thing not be counted as a character class

Comment: great! :) thank you! VIM is amazing! Where would you recommend for a beginner to learn regex?

Comment: @SaulloCastro there are some good regex tutorials on internet. read them, and try some example. important is you use it after reading and understanding. otherwise you'll forget it.

Answer (score 6):

If the pattern you wanted to negate was more than one character you could use a negative lookahead. Which matches if the pattern does NOT match the current position.

```
/ts\[\(j\)\@!.\{-}]
```

or with very magic

```
/\vts\[(j)@!.{-}]
```

Where the pattern being negated if right before `@!` in this case the `j`. The `.{-}` is a non-greedy match that is used to match everything until the next square bracket.

Comment: @SaulloCastro Its more complicated however its more powerful. The other answers just negate a character class which is negating a single letter. This you can negate any pattern you want to.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
/ts[[][^j]]
```

or escaping the `[`:

```
/ts\[[^j]]
```

Comment: this worked too... thank you! Where would you recommend for a beginner to learn regex?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) article should serve as a good starting point.